# Bash: Spurious "command not found" messages (I think)

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a simple utility function in Bash, which will perform an "action" in the given directory.  So I am basically abstracting the "go to a directory, do something, and come back" pattern.

```
inDir() {
    if [$# -le 1]; then
        return;
    else
        local dir="$1";
        local action="$2";
        local cwd=`pwd`;

        if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
            cd "$dir";
            $action;
            cd "$cwd";
        else 
            return;
        fi
    fi
}
```

Unfortunately, I get what I think is a spurious error when I run this, and I'm not sure where it is coming from.  For example:

```
$ inDir "/tmp" "touch hi"
```

correctly creates the file /tmp/hi, but also gives the error:

```
[2: command not found
```

I'm not sure if this matters to reading the error, but my prompt starts off with a "[".

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite what it might look like, '[' is actually a command called `test`, so:

```
if [$# -le 1]; then
```

should be:

```
if [ $# -le 1 ]; then
```

Note the space between the '[' and the next bit of code. Without it, the code reads as

```
test$#
```

which I think is obviously wrong. You also need a space before the closing square-bracket, which isn't a command, but is a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

@NeilButterworth answer is correct.

bash tries to solve the above common error and introduces built-in numeric compare structure `(())`.
For example:

```
if (($# < 1)); then
fi
```

The advanteges over `[]` structure is that it used regular compare operators (e.g. <, >, ==) and doesn't requires space as `[]` does.

For string comparison there's similar structure `[[]]`

Comment: +1 This is nice, but the disadvantage is that your Bash scripts are  no longer Bourne shell compatible. Most of mine still are (I think), in a probably futile effort to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

Life is simpler if you use sub-shells

```
( cd "$dir"; $action )
```

Has no effect on the current shell.

Comment: Event sub-shell may not be required. Since change directory is performed in script, it doesn't alters working directory of the bash instance the script was executed from.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you with handling more complex arguments

```
inDir() {
    if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
        local dir="$1"
        shift

        if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
            cd "$dir"
            "$@"
            cd -
        fi
    fi
}
```

So now you can do something like:

```
inDir /foo touch "file name with spaces"
```